# Différence entre "retour positif" et "retour plutôt positif"

Tags: expressions

Bonjour,

Je me demande s'il y a une différence entre "retour positif" et "un retour plutôt positif".

Comment: Retour de quoi ou de qui, dans quelles circonstances ?

Comment: Il y a quelques décennies, le bilan « globalement positif » de l'URSS avait fait beaucoup parler de lui...

Comment: @Personne en gros, c'est le retour du client (qui m'a déjà dit qu'on t'aime bien) à mon commercial par rapport à ma mission.

Comment: Commercialement, c'est *un retour positif*, c'est un métier où l'optimisme, la valorisation de ses actions, *savoir-faire et faire-savoir* l'emportent sur la demi-mesure. En revanche le comptable qui a eu des difficultés pour recouvrer ses créances sera tenté par *un retour **plutôt** positif*, oxymore si le ton de *plutôt* indique qu'on lui met un couteau sur la gorge pour qu'il accepte le retour de ce client qu'il a voué aux gémonies.

Comment: @Personne bien dit

Answer (score 3):

*Retour plutôt positif* n'est pas totalement positif - il y a probablement quelques remarques négatives, même si la plus grande partie de la réponse est positive et que les remarques négatives ne concernent rien d'essentiel.

Comment: Je serais un peu moins optimiste que toi. *Plutôt positif*, c'est juste au dessus de la moyenne, il y a un peu plus de satisfaits que d'insatisfaits.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, on peut le voir comme ça aussi... en fait, j'avais des situations un peu differents dans la tête: comme une demande de financement ou un envoi d'une article à une revue scientifique - *le retour plutôt positif* dans ces cas typiquement signifie qu'il n'y a pas des defauts graves, mais il faut encore travailler pour l'acceptation.

Comment: En tout cas, mieux vaut un ***retour plutôt positif*** qu'un ***retour plutôt négatif*** :-)

Answer (score 1):

Je trouve deux sens à **plutôt**

- Celui de [Roger Vadim](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51294/16669) qui appuie l'approximation
- La différence avec l'attendu et l'ajout de l'attendu.

On attendait quelque chose et on obtient autre chose et, par politesse ou à titre contributif, on dit  `plutôt...`

Par exemple
`Les gens sont silencieux par ici (on répond) non ils sont plutôt calmes`

Ils ne sont pas silencieux du tout mais et leur bruit n'est pas muet selon celui qui répond parceque le premier se basait sur le volume plutôt bas et négligeable pour lui. Mais le deuxième s'oppose"il y a du bruit ... C'est autre chose" et il ajoute "c'est le calme" ( par politesse ou simplement complémenter le premier... C'est pas ça mais c'est presque ça )

**Donc**

"retour positif" et "retour plutôt positif", le deuxième dit " c'est pas ce que j'attendais" et ajouter par politesse " mais je l'admet ... ( Ou autre chose)